# Proving that $D$ divides $f(Dj + d)$ for $f(d) = D$

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

I was working on some problems and got stumped on this one:

> *In a polynomial $f(d) = ad^2 + bd + c$. Given there is an integer $d$ for which $f(d)$ has an absolute value greater than $1$. Letting $D = f(d)$, show that $D$ divides $f(Dj+d)$ for every integer $j$.*

I understand how this works with an example, but I'm having a hard time figuring out a general proof for this.

This is a part of a bigger question, but I wanted help on this part in particular because I'm not able to proceed without a generalized proof.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know anything more about $f$?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I forgot to mention that f(d) is a polynomial. I added that in now. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: And $f$ is any polynomial? Or any 2nd degree polynomial, like $f(d)=ad^2+bd+c$?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(Dj+d)=a(Dj+d)^2+b(Dj+d)+c\\=aD^2j^2+2aDjd+\color{green}{ad^2}+bDj+\color{green}{bd}+\color{green}{c}\\=\color{green}{f(d)}+aD^2j^2+2aDjd+bDj$$

Can you show from here that $f(Dj+d)$ is divisible by $D=f(d)$?

Comment: I understand now! I didn't realize that f(d) was present in the expansion. Thank you very much!